# E-tender system

Tags: web-apps

I'm looking for an e-tender system, preferred to be developed by Java technologies.

I prefer it would be open sourced but if there are some other commercial with good features I don't mind.

Brief about the systems:

- For now I need it contains **open tender** tender's type with ability to apply **invited tender** type later.
- Got **notifications** module that notifies the buyer and the supplier with the tenders updates.
- For sure it must have **administration** module to create, edit and delete user's details.
- Search and browse tender advertisements and invitations.
- Register to receive notifications of new or upcoming opportunities.
- Advertise request for tenders.
- Send notifications to registered businesses about new opportunities.
- Provide access to tender documentation and other detailed information.

Comment: We need more info, please [edit] your question. What kind of tenders, what would be the request and response data? And do you (also) mean for free if you write open source?

Comment: This question needs a domain tag (i.e., what it’s about). I don’t know this domain, someone got an idea?

Comment: any recommendations ?